# How do I reference a Query in a Custom Function?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a custom function by referencing the Excel Object Model. By first going to Create/Module/Tools/References/ and selecting Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library (Access 2010) I was able to allow Access to bring-in the Excel Object Model. From there, I created a basic function in Acces using the Excel functions ACOS and COS. I was then able to run this function in my Query without issue. Here is the function:

```
Public Function myTestFunction(x As Double) As Double
        myTestFunction = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Acos(Cos(50))
End Function
```

This test function is generally meaningless to me, but was a good first step in achieving my ultimate goal. The next step was to reference a column in my Query within the function itself. Basically, I want to replace the 50 value with each row in my Query column [LAT]. Here is what I've tested:

```
Public Function myTestFunction(x As Double) As Double     
        myTestFunction = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Acos(Cos([Queries].[Data Query]![LAT]))
End Function
```

After attempting to run this function in my Query I receive the following error:

```
Run-Time Error 424
Object Required
```

My question is, how can I reference the Query column [LAT] within my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise your function to operate on its *x* argument.

```vb
Public Function myTestFunction(x As Double) As Double
    'myTestFunction = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Acos(Cos(50))
    myTestFunction = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Acos(Cos(x))
End Function
```

Then you can use the function in a query and give it your `[LAT]` field value.

```sql
SELECT dq.[LAT], myTestFunction(dq.[LAT])
FROM [Data Query] AS dq;
```